# Need regex to match two rather similar URL patterns

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I need a regex (to be used in .htaccess) with the following attributes, capturing the four-digit number and the text following it:

Match:
/9876/text_text_more_text_still_more_text
/8765/1234_text_text_text

Do not match:
/2010/08/01/text_text_more_text_still_more_text
/2010/08/01/text-text-more-text-still-more-text

So far I have:
/([0-9]+)/([^-/]+)

This unfortunately matches the do-not-match pattern. I'm definitely a neophyte at regexes but I think if I had a pointer in the right direction I could figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^/(\d{4})/(\w+)$
```

Comment: I didn't know \w included numbers, but this definitely seems to work. Nice simple pattern.

Comment: \w includes any "word" character, i.e. digits, letters and underscore. However implementations may vary, and include other characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex

```
^/\d{4}/[^/]*?$
```

Comment: The important point here is the start and end anchors, `^` and `$`. Without them, the regex can match `/2010/08/` **`01/text_text`**.

Comment: As modified to capture the two pieces I need:

`^/(\d{4})/([^/]*?)$`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the entire string is only the URL, you could try the following pattern:

```
^/[0-9]+/(([0-9]{4}_)?[^/]+)$
```

A quick explanation of my approach

- **^** represents the beginning of the string, **$** the end of the string
- **/[0-9]+/** is the first number URL
- **([0-9]{4}_)?** is the additional optional starting four digit number.
- **[^/]+** will represent any characters not including a forward slash to the end of the string.

Comment: I don't think the OP is looking to capture the second number, so `([0-9]{4}_)?` may be redundant.

Comment: Actually the parens here are merely to allow the '0 or 1' operator on the four numbers. As a side-effect they could be captured, but can also be ignored.

Comment: This one did not work for me. Matching was as expected but the second part was not captured.

Comment: I did leave out the second capture. ^/[0-9]+/(([0-9]{4}_)?[^/]+)$ will do it.